# Change maximum number of Virtual interfaces in Kernel

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-14.04, multicast

I am running Ubuntu server 14.04.3.

I have smcroute installed - Version 0.95, Build 130523. When I attempt to start the daemon I get the error message: `ERRO: addVIF, out of VIF space;`, this happens after it attempts to add the 33rd network interface of my machine.

Looking in `mroute.h` in `/usr/include/linux/` folder, I saw a `MAXVIFS` defined as `32`, so I upped it to `100` and saved the file.

After a reboot I can still see the 32 limit being imposed, but the file still states `100`. How can I force the OS to read from this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand why that number is 32. And that comes from the line below where `MAXVIFS` is defined:

```
typedef unsigned long vifbitmap_t;      /* User mode code depends on this lot */
```

On a 32bit machine (which is where this ancient crap started), that would a 32bit register. When you want a bitmap bigger than a register, things get messy. (see also: the `FD_SET()` macros) 64 is safe on a 64bit machine.

To increase the number of interfaces, you need to change both the userspace define (the file you changed) ***AND*** the define in the kernel (`include/linux/mroute.h` within the kernel source.) Then, rebuild your kernel and *every* userspace application that messes with multicast.

** Changing that define alters an ioctl data structure. **

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild (and reinstall) the kernel with the modified config.  There are Ubuntu-specific instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but just because you have many interfaces you don't have to recompile your kernel.  Try a [newer version of SMCRoute](https://github.com/troglobit/smcroute/releases) instead.  You can start it with `-N` and specify in `smcroute.conf` which interfaces you intend to route between using the `phyint` directive.  See the man page for more help.